# Is checking for type instead of null a reasonable choice?

Tags: c#, .net, null

One of my (senior) coworkers does something really strange in his code.

Instead of checking a variable for null, he checks for the type. And because

> null is FooType

actually returns false, this works.

```
public class Foo
{
    private string _bar = null;

    public string Bar
    {
        get
        {
            // strange way to check for null
            return (_bar is string) ? _bar : "";
        }
        set { _bar = value; }
    }
}
```

I think this is bad coding and Resharper seems to agree with me. Is there any reason to write the check this way?

Is this a valid way to check the variable? Or can this be considered bad style or maybe even harmful in some special cases?

I don't want to confront him unless I am sure that this actually does not make sense.

Comment: Does your senior coworker has a vb background by any chance?

Comment: I think so, yes. Or vbscript at least. Is this a common expression in VB?

Comment: Older versions of VB lacked much in the way of useful shorthand operators, so the above would have been the shorthand version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a good way. A better way would be to just:

```
return _bar ?? string.Empty;
```

Is it clear when you read your colleagues code that he is looking for nulls? No, then it isn't a good choice. Probably what the "is" operator will do first is just check for null and then return false. So it becomes much cleaner to just do that yourself. Or just use the null-coalescing operator

Comment: "Is it clear when you read your colleagues code that he is looking for nulls?" No, but what else could he be checking for when the variable he checks clearly is string?

Comment: @atticae Does that make it a valid use of it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I assumed he could only be checking for null because the variable he checks ("_bar" above) is always of type string.

Comment: Actually, the IL operator behind `is` and `as` is the same, "isinst", which acts pretty much like `as`; it checks to see if the popped reference is an instance of a passed class identifier, and pushes the instance if true, null if not. `as` uses `isinst` pretty much verbatim, while `is` additionally tests that the pushed result of isinst is null.

Comment: So, in IL terms, `if(_bar is string)` is evaluated very similarly to `if(_bar as string == null)`, and whichever way you want to think about it, null is null so the result of `isinst` will always be null whether it returned the instance reference (thinking null was a particular type) or the null reference (thinking it wasn't).

Comment: @KeithS That makes this usage even worse in terms of performance

Comment: I just checked the above code with ILSpy, it seems the compiler optimizes it to `if (this._bar != null)`.

Comment: @atticae - You certainly could do that but a string will never be a null reference, it might contain a null character, certainly won't be `NULL`  You might appreciate my explaination of what his code is doing.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm not sure what to tell you. I tested it and if _bar has null assigned the expression (_bar is null) evaluates to false.

Comment: @Ramhound Sure a string can be null. Why do you think method `string.IsNullOrEmpty` exists?

Answer (score 3):

I think this code is completely confusing and would never use it.   `_bar` is declared as a `string` so this type check is just begging people to not understand the code.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah that's a little odd. Why not just write:

```
return _bar ?? "" ;
```

When I need to do something like this, I have a little class to handle these details:

```
public class DefaultableValue<T>
{
    private T m_Value = default(T);
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsInvalidPredicate(m_Value))
            {
                m_Value = IfDefaultValueFunc();
            }
            return m_Value;
        }
    }
    private Predicate<T> IsInvalidPredicate { get; set; }
    private Func<T> IfDefaultValueFunc { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator T(DefaultableValue<T> property)
    {
        return property.Value;
    }
    public DefaultableValue(Predicate<T> isInvalidPredicate,Func<T> ifDefaultFunc)
        : this(default(T), isInvalidPredicate, ifDefaultFunc)
    {
    }
    public DefaultableValue(T initValue, Predicate<T> isInvalidPredicate, Func<T> ifDefaultFunc)
    {
        this.m_Value = initValue;
        this.IsInvalidPredicate = isInvalidPredicate;
        this.IfDefaultValueFunc = ifDefaultFunc;
    }
}
```

Then my class looks like

```
class Test
{
    DefaultableValue<string> AString { get; set; }

    public Test(string initialValue)
    {
        this.AString = new DefaultableValue<string>(initialValue, 
            (value) => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value),
            () => string.Empty);
    }
}

....
var test = new Test(null);
var someString = test.AString; // = "" not null
```

Comment: There are too many people out there that have never heard of `??`.

Answer (score 0):

if the above public property was declared to return `object` instead of `string`, the above could make sense. However, because it is returning string, that type of check does not make sense. If you want to return an empty string that you could do something like this:

```
public class Foo 
{ 
    private string _bar = null; 

    public string Bar 
    { 
        get 
        {  
            return (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(_bar)) ? "": _bar; 
        } 
        set { _bar = value; } 
    } 
}
```